# How to properly display an image with specific color range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some `.png` images which are being used as masks. The problem with these masks is that they contain just a few values e.g. only 12 values 0-11. I would like to be able to display them in a useful (for me) way, meaning to be able to optically distinguish the different values.

I have tried this approach:

```
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np 
im = Image.open('mask.png')
im.show()  # it all black but different values exist
len(set(list(im.getdata())))
a = 255 / np.amax(np.array(im))
im = im * a
im = Image.fromarray(im)
im.show()
```

which just project the [0,11] values to [0,255) values but it looks too awkward and inefficient. It contains too much conversion for just a simple display of my image.

I also tried to make it work with `matplotlib.pyplot` with its `colormap` option but lost in the process and couldn't find how to specify my range of values.

1. Is there an option to properly display my image using `PIL` or `pillow`?
2. Also what is the approach to achieve the above goal using `matplotlib`?

It's obvious that I am not really interested in the exact representation of my data, so round up errors using the above approach are of no concern.

Edit:

If it makes it any clearer my images are gray scale ones with range from 0 to a small value: `[0, N], N << 255`. Something like (toy example) that:

```
w, h = 20, 20
data = np.zeros((h, w))
data[5:10, 10:20] = 1
data[6:10, 0:15] = 2
data[10:15, 4:15] = 4
# it's displayed as a black image
Image.fromarray(data).show()
# it's displayed as image with distinguishable values
Image.fromarray(data*255/np.amax(data)).show()
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `len(set(list(im.getdata())))` line? BTW, the usual way to convert a PIL image to a Numpy array is with `np.asarray(img)`.

Comment: @PM 2Ring I just use it (in interactive mode) to check that there actually different values (it all appear black in the image display)

Comment: If you know that the maximum value is 11 then there's no need to use `np.amax`. But apart from that, converting from an Image to an array with `np.asarray(img)` then multiplying, and converting back to Image with `Image.fromarray(im)` is actually quite efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visualise arrays in matplotlib using `imshow()` and use a colorbar to easily show what the colours represent:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image 

# If not using fake data:
# im = Image.open('mask.png')
# data = np.array(im)

data = np.random.randint(0,12,(6,6)) # random values between 0 and 11

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(data)
plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can change the range of the colorbar (and hence the displaying of the data) using the arguments `vmin` and `vmax` in `imshow()`:

```
im = ax.imshow(data, vmin=0, vmax=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to display the image using a colormap of values [0,20] even if values in the specific image range [0,10] for example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As in change the range of the colorbar? Or actually change the data itself?

Comment: Change the range of the colormap. In the example above the equivalent would be to change `255/np.amax(data)` with a arbitrary value. Maybe it's identical with colorbar range change but I am not sure.

Comment: I don't want to actually change my data. Just change the way they display. I am seeking for a similar functionality as this of matlab `imshow(I,[low high])`

Comment: OK, I think I know what you mean. I've updated my answer again